# How do I determine number of bytes needed to represent a given integer?

Tags: java, byte

I need a function in Java to give me number of bytes needed to represent a given integer. When I pass 2 it should return 1, 400 -> 2, 822222 -> 3, etc.

@Edit: For now I'm stuck with this:

```
numOfBytes = Integer.highestOneBit(integer) / 8
```

Don't know exactly what highestOneBit() does, but have also tried this:

```
numOfBytes = (int) (Math.floor(Math.log(integer)) + 1);
```

Which I found on some website.

Comment: All ints are represented by a 32 bit memory space. So what you are asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar He's probably asking for the minimum number of bytes needed to represent a number (removing leading zeros).

Comment: Just a simple if cascade is all you need there - simple is best. Although it's not completely clear how you'd want to handle negative numbers.

Comment: The problem is; it all depends on how you plan to encode it.  e.g. one byte can store -128 to 127 or 0 to 255.  Four bytes could represent a signed or unsigned `int` value or be a `float` and represent different values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static int byteSize(long x) {
    if (x < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int s = 1;
    while (s < 8 && x >= (1L << (s * 8))) s++;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: never consider negative number?

Answer (score 4):

`Integer.highestOneBit(arg)` returns only the highest set bit, in the original place. For example, `Integer.highestOneBit(12)` is 8, not 3. So you probably want to use `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(Integer.highestOneBit(12))`, which does return 3. Here is the [Integer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros%28int%29)

Some sample code:

```
numOfBytes = (Integer.numberOfTrailingZeroes(Integer.highestOneBit(integer)) + 8) / 8;
```

The `+ 8` is for proper rounding.

Answer (score 2):

The lazy/inefficient way to do this is with [`Integer#toBinaryString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29). It will remove all leading zeros from positive numbers for you, all you have to do is call [`String#length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) and divide by `8`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how to solve the same problem using normal decimal numbers. Then apply the same principle to binary / byte representation i.e. use 256 where you would use 10 for decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int byteSize(long number, int bitsPerByte) {
    int maxNumberSaveByBitsPerByte = // get max number can be saved by bits in value bitsPerByte
    int returnValue = getFloor(number/maxNumberSaveByBitsPerByte); // use Math lib
    if(number % maxNumberSaveByBitsPerByte != 0)
            returnValue++;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For positive values: 0 and 1 need 1 digit, with 2 digits you get the doubled max value, and for every digit it is 2 times that value. So a recursive solution is to divide:

```
public static int binaryLength (long l) {
    if (l < 2) return 1; 
    else 1 + binaryLength (l /2L);
}
```

but shifting works too:

```
public static int binaryLength (long l) {
    if (l < 2) return 1; 
    else 1 + binaryLength (l >> 1);
}
```

Negative values have a leading 1, so it doesn't make much sense for the question. If we assume binary1 is decimal1, binary1 can't be -1. But what shall it be? b11? That is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Why you wouldn't do something simple like this:

```
private static int byteSize(int val) {
    int size = 0;
    while (val > 0) {
        val = val >> 8;
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int numOfBytes = (Integer.SIZE >> 3) - (Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n) >> 3);
```

This implementation is compact enough while performance-friendly, since it doesn't involve any floating point operation nor any loop.

It is derived from the form:

```
int numOfBytes = Math.ceil((Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)) / Byte.SIZE);
```

The magic number `3` in the optimized form comes from the assumption: `Byte.SIZE` equals `8`